# CustomDataGridViewColumn vs DataGridViewTextBoxColumn with custom sort

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Hi I currently have a DataGridView where the first column contains the name of a person which until now I've been manually setting the value as a string which represents the `Person` object. The rest of the columns contain other classes/strings.

I've just been trying to assign the person to the cell value to make it easier to find the person who is attached to that cell. I added the ToString() method to my Person class and all worked well until I tried to sort the column using

```
_dataGridView.Sort(_dataGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

I get an ArgumentException saying the Object must be of type String (I'm using text box column)

I've tried implementing my own sort method but got an issue with casting the cell value as a Person (says cannot cast string to person) even though I assign a Person as the Value.

```
public void _rotaView_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        Person a = (Person)e.CellValue1;
        Person b = (Person)e.CellValue2;

        e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'RotaManagerSolution.Person'.

So any ideas on how I can store the custom class in a datagridview cell value and still be able to sort it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem was to databind a custom sortable list to the DataGridView by doing the following

Create the first column with the data property set to the `Name` property of the `Person` class

```
// Add column for names (people and shifts)
DataGridViewColumn names = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
names.DataPropertyName = "Name";
names.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
names.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
names.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
_rotaView.Columns.Add(names);
```

then added this custom sortable binding list found [here](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html)

To bind the data

```
 SortableBindingList<Person> sblist = new SortableBindingList<Person>();

 foreach (Person p in _mainManager.ListOfPeople)
 {
     sblist.Add(p);
 }
 _rotaView.DataSource = sblist;
```

This then allows me to call this line to sort the list

```
_rotaView.Sort(_rotaView.Columns[0], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is the solution I implemented which answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I have updated the sample code based on my understanding of your requirement.

You can use a mix of dynamic objects and Sortable `BindingList` to accomplish your goal.

Let say these are your entities:

```
class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Contact { get; set; }
    public Address HQAddress { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
   public int Height { get; set; }
   public float Weight { get; set; }
}
```

This is your data:

```
Person p1 = new Person() { Name = "Hari", DOB = new DateTime(1781, 4, 3), Height = 165, Weight = 60.0f};
Person p2 = new Person() { Name = "Nil", DOB = new DateTime(1781, 4, 3), Height = 165, Weight = 60.0f};

Company c = new Company()
{
    Name = "Sahaj Technologies",
    Contact = p1,
    HQAddress = new Address() { City = "Sarang", Country = "India" }
};
```

Then you could use the following code to populate your grid. Notice that it is using data from different entities. In fact, since dynamic objects are used, it doesn't matter where your data comes from.

```
dgv.DataSource = GetSortableBindingList(
    new[] {
        new { CompanyName = c.Name, ContactPerson = c.Contact.Name, HQ = c.HQAddress.City + ", " + c.HQAddress.Country},
        new { CompanyName = "Akshar Inc.", ContactPerson = p2.Name, HQ = "LA, USA"}
    }
);
// Wrapper method to allow dynamic objects
public object GetSortableBindingList<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : class
{
    return new ObservableCollection<T>(collection).ToBindingList();
}
```

Here is the link to working demo:
http://share.linqpad.net/5257ki.linq

P.S. To run this demo you need to follow these steps:

1. Download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/GetFile.aspx?LINQPad4-AnyCPU.zip).
2. Get EntityFramework.dll. Follow instructions as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906).
3. Extract LINQPad, copy the EntityFramework.dll in the same folder as LINQPad.exe
4. Download the [demo](http://share.linqpad.net/5257ki.linq) file, open it with LINQPad and hit F5.

---

Comment: Hi Ravi, I've added a bit more detail to the question, I only have the Person class in the first column, the rest have other things in them so not sure about how the data source would work (only used data source with combo box so far).

Also could you explain how using the observable collection actually sorts the data grid view?

Comment: To support sorting (i.e when you click on column header, data in grid is sorted by that column) `DataGridView` requires sortable `BindingList<T>`. You could write your own implementation of it. Or else you can use one provided by an extension method of `ObservableCollection<T>` class. This extension is defined in EntitiFramework.dll.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I took your idea of a setting the data source as a sortable binding list and using a custom class I found to fix the problem and posted the solution I implemented which works great. Thanks

Comment: Downvoter please care to comment why you felt compelled to do so.